# How do I center two images together?

Tags: image, center

Right now, both my images are towards the left. They are side by side but for some reason, they aren't centering. This is my CSS code for them right now:

```
img.photo{
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 5px;
}
```

what else will get them centered?

Comment: can you show example in a fiddle or screenshot of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float and text-align. Add a div around both of the images with the text-align in that.

```css
img.photo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centre">
  <img class="photo" src="http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/76000/76818/microsoft-small-basic-22.jpg" />

  <img class="photo" src="http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/76000/76818/microsoft-small-basic-22.jpg" />
</div>
```